# How to include directory tree for back-up using cpio?

Tags: backup, cpio

I am backing up files including directories from 1 partition to other using `cpio`. `cpio` works perfect for backing but I am unable to backup directory tree. I am in a partition mounted on the directory as shown below. In that partition, I am in the directory `/b/c`. It contains 3 files 'd, e & f'. Also it contains a directory named g which in turn includes files 'h & j'. Please see below.

```
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:/media/ravbholua/c09fb098-0402-418a-b1e5-8888848a5636/b/c$ ls *
d  e  f

g:
h  j
```

Now I want to back up all these files (d, e, f, h & j) including directory structure on to a different partition. I have created file (or archive in this case) named 'mark'. Please see below. Using `cpio` I am transferring to archive named 'mark'.

```
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:/media/ravbholua/c09fb098-0402-418a-b1e5-8888848a5636/b/c$ ls -R /med*/ravb*/*36/b/c/* | cpio -ov > /med*/ravb*/*9f/mark
/media/ravbholua/c09fb098-0402-418a-b1e5-8888848a5636/b/c/d
/media/ravbholua/c09fb098-0402-418a-b1e5-8888848a5636/b/c/e
/media/ravbholua/c09fb098-0402-418a-b1e5-8888848a5636/b/c/f
cpio: blank line ignored
cpio: /media/ravbholua/c09fb098-0402-418a-b1e5-8888848a5636/b/c/g:: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
cpio: h: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
cpio: j: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
1 block
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:/media/ravbholua/c09fb098-0402-418a-b1e5-8888848a5636/b/c$
```

`cpio` perfectly transferred the immediate files (d, e & f) in the directory. Problem comes for the directory g and the subdirectory files. It's apparent that `cpio` requires regular files and doesn't entertain directory. So, now so that the tool `cpio` includes the directory tree, anyhow I have to give cpio the subdirectory files 'h & j' under directory 'g'. How to do that.
`ls, ls -R, etc.` can't provide only the files in their output, they include directory also.

So, please tell me is there any option to ls or any other command that will output ***only*** the files in the directory tree. Have a look below:

```
$ (command that will output the below)

/media/ravbholua/c09fb098-0402-418a-b1e5-8888848a5636/b/c/d
/media/ravbholua/c09fb098-0402-418a-b1e5-8888848a5636/b/c/e
/media/ravbholua/c09fb098-0402-418a-b1e5-8888848a5636/b/c/f
/media/ravbholua/c09fb098-0402-418a-b1e5-8888848a5636/b/c/g/h
/media/ravbholua/c09fb098-0402-418a-b1e5-8888848a5636/b/c/g/j
```

> EDIT

I'm editing my Q with some correction so that any viewer of this thread would get clear and right information. I mentioned that `cpio` doesn't accept directories based on what I felt from the output of `ls` command. But its wrong. `cpio` accepts directories even. So, `cpio` to me seems to be a very great tool for backing up selected files or complete partition/disk.

Answer (score 3):

You should not process the output from `ls` into `cpio`. The 'standard' way of getting file names into cpio is using `find`:

```
find /med*/ravb*/*36/b/c/* -type f | cpio ...
```

or on Linux systems:

```
find /med*/ravb*/*36/b/c/* -type f -print0 | cpio -0 ...
```

that handles file names with newlines and other special characters as well.
`-type f` only selects files.

Comment: yes it has worked fantastically and `-d` option helped recovery. Thank you. cpio seems to me to be a great tool for backing up data, whether its some specific files & directories or the complete partition/disk. What do you say?

Comment: If I create a hidden file (ex.: .usa) under directory `c`, its not included in the back-up but if the hidden file is anywhere else in the directory tree (ex.: .../b/c/g), its getting included. As `*` ignores the hidden file, its not included under `c` directory. So, its better to remove *. The numeral `0` suffixed to print and as an option to cpio: has it any significance because I'm seeing `0` like this 1st time.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a good resource here:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1459/bkupsavefiles-21.html

> -d Creates directories as needed.

Comment: seems to be a very good link. I will go through it. Thank you

Comment: Thanks once again for providing the `-d` option. I backed up the files using the command as mentioned by Zelda. Then I deleted the original only to test the recovery. Now `-d` came for my rescue.

Answer (score -1):

One of my simple examples:

```bsh
for dir in it work; do  
    cd /home/$USER/$dir/  
    for file_ext in csv docx pdf txt xlsx; do  
        find . -depth -iname "*.$file_ext" -print0 | cpio --null -dmpv /home/$USER/Dropbox/$dir/  
    done  
done  
cd
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note that your approach is very similar to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/104842/377345) by @Zelda, so you may want to point out the differences in your respective approaches to the problem.